# Redirect to https if url point to another webserver by means of proxypass

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need help about a configuration. I have an .htaccess for my frontend webserver which is so configured:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(dir_a|dir_b|dir_c)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/?(dir_a|dir_b|dir_c)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]    
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

So, dir_a, dir_b and dir_c, which are on the frontend server, are not redirected to https. Everything on the frontend server is correctly redirected to https if https is omitted or using http when one inputs an URL of my website. This does not happen for a location pointing to an internal webserver, i.e I have in my apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  ServerName example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ...
</VirtualHost>
...
<Location /backsrvdir>
  SSLRequireSSL
  ProxyPass http://192.168.x.y/backsrvdir
  ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.x.y/backsrvdir
</Location>
```

In backsrvdir I have another .htaccess with its DirectoryIndex bsindex.php.
It works only if the link already contains https:, so if I write or click on https://example.com/backsrvdir it's ok, if omit https: or using http: the frontend server responds with a "403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /backsrvdir/ on this server. Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 80".
As I stated above, port 80 is open only for dir_a dir_b and dir_c.
Any idea to solve the problem and have http://example.com/backsrvdir redirected to https://example.com/backsrvdir?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: But your two configurations are different, why would you expect them to behave the same? `SSLRequireSSL` will explicitly forbid access over plain http, and that is exactly what happens.

Comment: If I comment out SSLRequireSSL /backsrvdir becomes accessible from http. I don't want that, I want it be accessible only from https and if http (or nothing) is used, it must be however redirected to https.

Comment: Just add the same RewriteRule as in your first configuration

Comment: Yes I comment out SSLRequireSSL but the variable %{HTTP_HOST} in the backend server is substituted with ip address of backend server, no more the original example.com: I obtain https: // 192.168.x.y/backsrvdir instead of https: // example.com/backsrvdir

Comment: 1) add a line with `ProxyPreserveHost On` directly above `ProxyPass ...`, 2) Don't put RewriteRule in .htaccess, place it also in apache2.conf, above Proxy.. lines

Comment: I put "ProxyPreserveHost On" in <VirtualHost * :443> section? Because server said it is not allowed in <Location /backsrvdir> (Apache 2.2 do not allows it, only Apache 2.4 allows it). And I have not fully understood how is the RewriteRule: which rule.... the rule in .htaccess of backend server should be put in front end server? The rule I wrote in .htaccess backend server was: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  Redirect permanent /backsrvdir https://example.com/backsrvdir
  # Remove the other 3 lines:
  # SSLRequireSSL
  # ProxyPass http://192.168.x.y/backsrvdir
  # ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.x.y/backsrvdir
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also remove anything related to https redirection from `.htaccess`

Comment: But if I remove any reference to 192.168.x.y which is hosting backsrvdir, where do I put that reference? Somewhere I need to say that backsrvdir is hosted by 192.168.x.y....

Comment: You said that you don't want `/backsrvdir` to be accessible from http, so it is not needed in `<VirtualHost *:80>`. An you said that if you write or click on `https://example.com/backsrvdir` it's ok, so it already is somewhere in `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: It is not in <VirtualHost *:443> but it is only in <Location /backsrvdir> as I wrote in the first message.

Comment: I see, then <Location> segment in not inside any <VirtualHost>? If so, then move it inside <VirtualHost *:443>, and leave `Redirect...` in <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: I did it and it says: "Not Found. The requested URL /backsrvdir/ was not found on this server.". Well it's right: it is not in this (frontend) server that directory